# openWRT: admin control programmatically

Tags: openwrt

I can login to openWRT router admin portal to configure everything. However, if I want to control the openWRT device programmatically, i.e. sending the command through a socket connection between the openWRT device and the server, any module to recommend?

- add a user/password who can login to openWRT wifi network.
- QoS which can limit the bandwidth usage of a user; calculate the data
  usage for a user
- Security, create firewalls between different users on openWRT device.

Comment: Do you want to access the openwrt command line to execute commands...then ssh into it.

Comment: cannot ssh, the openWRT sits in the intranet. The connection is initiated by the openWRT device to a server in public domain

Comment: Allow ssh port to accept incoming connections.

Comment: what are the modules to program on in order to fulfil those three requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have just one router to manage, you can use ssh reverse tunnel: https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

You can establish an openvpn or ipsec tunnel as well.

If you want to control a network of devices, then you can look at different management protocols: TR-069 (freecwmp) and SNMP (net-snmp). However, this approach will require additional time to configure and use.

Comment: Thanks. SSH might not be a nice fit here. Wifidog's approach might be more appropriate. Two way socket communication need to be established for server to set command with web portal

Answer (score 0):

You can use Luci for the local connection.

If you want to create a program in Python or C/C++, I would suggest using `libcurl` library or module.

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of doing it on router, use radius application
  ([freeradius](https://freeradius.org/) if looking for opensource), freeradius works on
  mysql so you can define authentication details as well as
  authorization and data accounting there. Please explain your project
  so I can help you more.
- If you use radius<->router setup, you you need to manage/monitor only
  radius server, and radius server will take care of all the back-end
  process. As well as if you go with radius you can go other then
  openwrt router (I know fully openwrt supported model is more costly
  and hard to find). you can use those also because you are following
  industry standards.
- And last point if you want to design by your own that is very good,
  but I'll suggest first go with coova-chilli/nodogsplash (coovac-chilli
  has more options). Understand its working, then design your own
  model.